# Instructive video content for High School kids?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, online-resources

I need some math YouTube channels (or any other visual media, like movies) that I can recommend to High School students, not solely as a method of learning math but also to illustrate its beauty and applications.

Anything is okay even if it’s advanced, as long as it’s interesting.

Comment: I suppose now is as good a time as ever to plug my YouTube videos.  I'm (slowly) putting together a series on Ramsey Theory, and I think it could be fairly accessible to high school students so long as they have a bit of tenacity (and some experience with induction).  See my profile for a link.

Comment: What about [ViHart](http://www.youtube.com/user/Vihart)?

Comment: ViHart seems great. Anything else? A list would be helpful

Comment: @hb20007 You might want to try asking this on [Math Educators SE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I didn't know it existed. I'll go there if I don't get something here

Comment: Motivated high school students might like my video on the barber paradox. It presents what I think is an innovative resolution based on elementary set theory. It may move a bit quickly for high school students -- just be ready with the pause button, or download the PowerPoint version. View it at my website at http://www.dcproof.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Movies**

- [A Beautiful Mind](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268978/)
- [Fermat’s Room](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1016301/)
- [Good Will Hunting](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119217/)
- [Pi](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138704/)
- [Stand and Deliver](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094027/)
- [The Imitation Game](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2084970/)
- [The Man Who Knew Infinity](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0787524/)

**TV Shows**

- [Dara Ó Briain’s School of Hard Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dara_%C3%93_Briain:_School_of_Hard_Sums)

**YouTube**

I recommend this playlist: [The MathemAttic: Best Math Videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkvmxOX1HCR6spJsw0iWSSHEfRIM6sstd)

*Great channels:*

- [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw)
- [Art of the Problem](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCotwjyJnb-4KW7bmsOoLfkg)
- [MindYourDecisions](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHnj59g7jezwTy5GeL8EA_g)
- [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoxcjq-8xIDTYp3uz647V5A)
- [singingbanana](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMpizQXRt817D0qpBQZ2TlA)
- [Stand-up Maths](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSju5G2aFaWMqn-_0YBtq5A)
- [Think Twice](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9yt3wz-6j19RwD5m5f6HSg)
- [Vihart](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOGeU-1Fig3rrDjhm9Zs_wg)
- [Welch Labs](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UConVfxXodg78Tzh5nNu85Ew)

(The resources are great for adults too.)